# Raw SQL with Doctrine

Tags: sql, doctrine

I want to execute a query in raw SQL with Doctrine. I have an error but I don't know where.

```
$my_id = 12;
$pdo = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection()->getDbh();
$q = 'SELECT date FROM my_table WHERE my_text LIKE "%'.$my_id.'%" ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1'; 
$r = $pdo->query($q)->fetchOne(); 
$result['date'] = $r->date;
```

The error is `$pdo->fetchOne();` : "Call to undefined method PDO::fetchOne()"
I have the same message with fetchAll().

How can it be fixed?

Comment: I dont have any message. The script is called by ajax, and I dont know  what's the problem in this lines. If I comment it, all is alright. Any idea ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Then how do you know you have an error?  You're going to have to get more specific if you want help.

Comment: After this code, I have no return for $result['date']. And the script is stopped. For example if I add a mail() send just after, it's not work. I think the error is here : $pdo->query($q)->fetchOne();
Is it possible ?

Comment: I have found error messages. I can't use fetchOne or fetchAll. How can I do ???

Comment: Well, glancing at the PDO documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), there isn't a `fetchOne` method.  Have you tried using `fetch` instead?

Comment: Problem fixed, here is the correct code :

$conn = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection();
$q = 'SELECT date FROM my_table WHERE ...'; 
$r = $conn->fetchAssoc($q);
echo $r[0]['date'];

Thansk all for help !

Comment: By all means, feel free to post your solution as an answer and accept it!

Answer (score 1):

Answer as written in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612280/raw-sql-with-doctrine-resolved#comment-9239735):

> Here is the correct code :
>
> ```
> $conn = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection(); 
> $q = 'SELECT date FROM my_table WHERE ...'; 
> $r = $conn->fetchAssoc($q); 
> echo $r[0]['date'];
> ```